# "got somebody something" vs "have got somebody something" "got something" vs "have got something"

Tags: word-meaning

In a movie, a man says:

> I got you a present.

Why don't he say:

> I have got you a present.

In another movie, I saw some sentences:

> Who's got champagne? Huh?
>
> I've got champagne.

Why don't they say:

> Who got champagne? Huh?
>
> I got champagne.

I'm confused by these sentences.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for @snailplane 's answer:

> If you say "I got you a present", get means 'acquire'. Most likely, it means you bought them something from a store.
>
> Have got is an idiom that means 'have; possess'.
>
> Like most people, I've got two eyes. = I have two eyes.